# Dynamically change toolbarColorScheme SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can you change the color of the status bar dynamically in SwiftUI? I can set it initially, but I'd like to have it dynamic.

`.toolbarColorScheme(statusColor, for: .navigationBar)`

In a perfect world, this is what I would like to do:

```
@State private var statusColor:ColorScheme = .dark  

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .toolbarColorScheme($statusColor, for: .navigationBar)
    }
```

And have the ability to change the value, for example:

```
func makeLight() {
     statusColor = .light
}

func makeDark() {
     statusColor = .dark
}
```

This doesn't seem possible. I've tried it multiple ways. The example above gives the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected
> argument type 'ColorScheme?'

Comment: Just remove the dollar sign: `.toolbarColorScheme(statusColor, for: .navigationBar)`

Comment: I tried that before I posted this. That has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach, works for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var statusColor: ColorScheme = .dark
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("change color scheme") {
                statusColor = statusColor == .dark ? .light : .dark
            }
            Text("main view")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button("change scheme") {
                            statusColor = statusColor == .dark ? .light : .dark
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("test", displayMode: .inline)
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarColorScheme(statusColor, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}
```